# Publish Shiny app with downloadable pdf document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, publish

I am trying to publish my app which I made with R Shiny and which works fine locally. However, I get the error: 
`An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.`

I figured out this is due to my r markdown file. In my app you can download a report, I used the code from this article to do this: (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html). Thus, my code in the app looks like this:

```
    output$Report <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("report.pdf")
        },

        content = function(file) {

          tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "Report.Rmd")
          file.copy("Report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

          params <- list(
            notes1 = input$Notes,
            notes2 = input$Notes2,
            notes3 = input$Notes3,
            notes4 = input$Notes4,
            choice = input$choice,
            data = my.final.data(),
            min = my.final.min(),
            max = my.final.max(),
            bins = my.final.bins(),
            fit = my.final.fit(),
            log = my.final.log()
          )

          rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                            params = params,
                            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
          )
        }
    )
```

The R markdownfile makes several plots, for example:

```
library(ggplot2)
if(!is.na(params$data)){
  if(params$log == TRUE) {
  p1 <- ggplot(params$data, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 20, color = "sienna4", fill = "sienna3") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    labs(title = "Histogram", x = "LR", y = "") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_x_log10(limits = c(params$min, params$max), breaks = params$bins)  
} else {
  p1 <- ggplot(params$data, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 20, color = "sienna4", fill = "sienna3") + 
    xlim(params$min, params$max)+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    labs(title = "Histogram", x = "LR", y = "") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
    theme_minimal()
}

p1
}
```

When I go to the logs of the app it shows the error:
`Error in: data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not a character vector`

What I think goes wrong is that the R markdown file can't be knitted on it's own to a pdf file since params is NA. I tried publishing the app without the markdown file and then the web app works but (ofcourse) you can't download the report.

How can I publish my app in such a way that you can still download the report? Or, are there any other ways how I can share the app?

Comment: Do you know that `params` is `NA`? Interesting. Either way, a side suggestion: if your rendering takes more than a few seconds, it is not uncommon for the download handler to timeout, stopping the process anyway (even if rendering did work).

Comment: Would you post your RMD header, please? And example data, if possible?